# Metric spaces - show $|A-B|^2$ is not a metric on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: metric-spaces

$$
d(A, B) = |A-B|^2
$$

I'm told to consider the following: For the Euclidean metric, denoted by $d_2$, and defined by

$$
d_2(A,B) = \sqrt{(x_A - x_B)^2 + (y_A - y_B)^2}
$$

How are they related, the later seems to be ($|A^2+B^2|$)

[image]

Comment: Actually  your $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$. So, check if the given function satisfies the triangle inequality? As such, it has nothing to do with the metric $d_2$ because for that your $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: How do the vectors A and B translate to this formula $|A-B|^2$

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, for the $d(A,B)$ function, your $A,B$ are real numbers (as in example 1.3.2) and not vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: How about choosing $A=0, B=1$ and $C=2$? Now check if $d(A,C) \leq d(A,B)+d(B,C)$? Note: deleting your comments is not useful as it breaks the chain for another user.

Comment: $A=0,B=1,C=2$ $d(a,c)=2 \le (d(a,b) = 1 + d(b, c) = 1) = 2$, It holds, its equal

Comment: $d(A,C)=|0-2|^{2}=4$.

Comment: But what is C, i'm only given two points. A and B, 0, and 1. Am I just picking C arbitrarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a map $d:X^2\to[0,\infty)$ to be a metric on $X$, it must satisfy the conditions for *all* pairs of points $(x,y)\in X^2$. So a single counterexample suffices. In this example, if $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=2$ then
$$
d(a,c) = |0-2|^2 = 4 > 2 = |0-1|^2 + |1-2|^2 = d(a,b)+d(a,c).
$$
It does not matter how we arrive at the counterexample, only that it is valid. Which in this case it is, in showing that the map $(x,y)\mapsto|x-y|^2$ is not a metric on $\mathbb R$, as the triangle inequality does not hold.